# Number of connected graphs with $l+1$ vertices, $l$ edges with multiplicities $m_1,\dots,m_l$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a question in combinatorics. I apologize in advance if some things I say do not make any sense, I don't know much about graph theory or combinatorics. This is a question which came up in a probability problem I'm working on. Let $k=2m$, $1\leq l\leq m$, and $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_l$ be even numbers such that $m_1+m_2+\dots+m_l=k$. What I would like to know is how many nonisomorphic connected graphs there are with $l+1$ distinct vertices, $l$ distinct edges having multiplicities $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_l$.

I would be especially grateful for any papers or books which are related to this problem.

Comment: If you have $l+1$ vertices and $l$ edges you have a tree.  The multiplicities have to be $1$ or the graph will be disconnected.  You are just looking for the number of trees on $l+1$ vertices.  The number is shown in http://oeis.org/A000055

Comment: Do you actually mean multiplicities or do you mean weights?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I have virtually no experience in graph theory. Though I think your question actually gives a better way to describe what I mean. I want to know the number of weighted trees on $l+1$ vertices where the weight on each edge is an even positive integer and the sum of all the weights is $k=2m$. More specifically for any set of positive even integers $m_1,\dots,m_l$ such that $m_1+m_2+\dots+m_l=k$ how many weighted trees there are with $m_1,\dots,m_l$ as the weights of the edges.